# Why my Flask application can't create new user using Python Social Auth?

Tags: flask, python-social-auth

I am using `python-social-auth` package, and it has rather strange behavior, that is, I can login using existing gmail account already signup in the database, but I can't register new user.

Actually, this is a dockerize Flask application (in `app.py`). If I am not using `supervisord`, all Python Social Auth behavior works fine. That's mean, I directly call `python app.py`, instead of configuring it to run by `supervisord` in `supervisord.conf`.

But if I use `supervisord`, new user will not get registered. Application will be directed to login page.

NOTE: on the other hand, I am trying to rewrite social implementation by using Flask-OAuth.

Comment: Can you show your code and supervisor config?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I found the bug in my code. I will post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the bug. These are code fix for custom pipeline for confirmed oauth process:

```
def pipeline_oauth_confirmed(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
   user.active = True
   user.confirmed_at = datetime.now()
   db_session.commit()
```

As the app need to have `user.active=True` before it logged in the user, the user wont' be logged in. I omitted the `db_session.commit()` call. Once that added, it works!